# Sending the output of AWS lambda through SNS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have the following code, where I want to send the output of previous function as an SNS email. However, when I run this I get "[ERROR] NameError: name 'i' is not defined". Can someone help, please or tell me how to do handle this in any other way? I am new to lambda so need help. Also, help me with some good reads to learn.

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('sns') 
def lambda_handler(event, context):
  instances = [i for i in boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='us-east-1').instances.all()]
# Print instance_id of instances that do not have a Tag of Key='Owner' and 'Env'
  for i in instances:
    if i.tags is not None and ('Owner') and ('Env') not in [t['Key'] for t in i.tags]:
      print ("missing tags in:- "+i.instance_id)
snsArn = 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:accountid:required_tags_are_missing'
message = i.instance_id
response = client.publish(
      TopicArn = snsArn,
      Message = message,
      Subject='Hello'
    )
```

Tried the solution as above, where I have tried to send the i.instance_id as message body.

Comment: Indentation matters. Your code is not correctly indented and therefore executes / runs quite differently to what you would want.

Comment: First of all, `message = i.instance_id` should be in for loop statement, and you better define the `message` variable as list since you want to return all of EC2 instances which are not tagged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be indented as follows:

```py
import boto3
client = boto3.client('sns') 

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  instances = [i for i in boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='us-east-1').instances.all()]
  # Print instance_id of instances that do not have a Tag of Key='Owner' and 'Env'
  for i in instances:
    if i.tags is not None and ('Owner') and ('Env') not in [t['Key'] for t in i.tags]:
      print ("missing tags in:- "+i.instance_id)
      snsArn = 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:accountid:required_tags_are_missing'
      message = i.instance_id
      response = client.publish(
        TopicArn = snsArn,
        Message = message,
        Subject='Hello'
      )
```

Update: To send all the instance ids in one email you can do the following.

```py
import boto3
client = boto3.client('sns') 

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  instances = [i for i in boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='us-east-1').instances.all()]
  # Print instance_id of instances that do not have a Tag of Key='Owner' and 'Env'
  instance_ids = []
  for i in instances:
    if i.tags is not None and ('Owner') and ('Env') not in [t['Key'] for t in i.tags]:
      print ("missing tags in:- "+i.instance_id)
      snsArn = 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:accountid:required_tags_are_missing'
      instance_ids.append(i.instance_id)
  response = client.publish(
    TopicArn = snsArn,
    Message = ",".join(instance_ids),
    Subject='Hello'
  )
```

Comment: Hi Nishant, thanks this did help. However, I am getting emails for all the instances separately, instead of list of ids in one email. Any suggestion on that?

Comment: Thanks Nishant, I tried this however not receiving the notification now.

Comment: Any specific error?

Comment: Please ignore I do get the instance id's. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I just have one more question. Can you suggest me how do I start learning about this? Any suggestions?

Comment: You can get started with https://pythonbooks.org/free-books/. Also youtube videos like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_uQrJ0TkZlc should help getting you started in this journey.